# Passing parameters through Ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a ajax function:

```
function abc(url){    
$.ajax({
                url:'/account/search',
                type:'GET',
                success:update(url),
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
}
```

On success,there is a function call to update:

```
   function update(response,url){
            list = response.data;
            var i=0;
            var q = list.length;
}
```

But it throws the error:**Cannot read property 'length' of undefined** in console.

As **update** function is already receiving data from an another file,which comes in the parameter **response**,so I can't remove it.

Please provide suggestions how to correctly pass a parameter(i.e. the "url" in this example) to the update function from AJAX call.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please print console.log(list) and console.log(response)

Comment: You're only passing one thing when calling update in your success function, the url. I'm assuming that is a string, that doesn't have data, therefore list in your code actually equals url.data. so list has no length. You can't use the response from another function in your new one, that variable is scoped to the first function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need another function. The `success` callback itself just received one parameter: the AJAX response. If you need a second one, you'll need a function call in between.

```
function abc(url){    
  $.ajax({
                url:'/account/search',
                type:'GET',
                success: function(data){ update(data, url); },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Will that be able to pull the `url` property from the surrounding object and pass it like that?

Comment: @James This will take the `url` parameter of `abc()` and pass it on, yes. Your error btw most likely is not related to this.

Comment: I need more coffee, I didn't spot the wrapping abc function.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**
Do not pass any parameter in success

```
function abc(url)
{    
  $.ajax({
                url:'/account/search',
                type:'GET',
                success: update,
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
}



function update(data){
            console.log(data)
            var q = data.length;
}
```

Comment: it's giving a list in form of:[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It may work in this scenario. Bind the value using this may work.

```js
   
   
     function addRemoveQuestion(id){
        
         
         var formData =    $("#q_"+id).serialize()  
         
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: window.location.href,
            data: formData,
            success: handleFormSuccess.bind(this, id) ,
            error: handleFormError,
        })
   }
   function handleFormSuccess( data, response,textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log( data)//id
        console.log(textStatus)
        console.log(jqXHR)
        console.log("#btn_"+data )
      
        
    }
```